# One to One relationship

Tags: sql-server

I am working on my final year project of bscs degree. I am struggling with the database design as I counter a problem of one to one relationship .I hope you will understand my problem and suggest me a finest solution.

There are three tables:

1. DomesticQuater(QuaterNo, Location, Address, AllocatedEmpID)
2. CommercialShops(ShopId, Location, ownername, ownernic)
3. ElectricMeter(meterno, meterphase)

Only one meter can be allocated to one User either DomesticQuater or commericalShops.

Now where should I place the foreign keys?

Comment: It seems that both your DomesticQuater and CommercialShops table are referencing a 4th table through the "Location" column. Won't it then make sense to place a Location-foreign key on the Electric Meter table, and put a Unique constraint on the foreign key (to ensure that no two meters can exist on the same Location)?

Comment: location is not a foreign key but the allocated emp in domesticquater is reference key of emp table

Comment: Okay. Ideally, since both DomesticQuaters and CommercialShops represent physical locations, you should have a PhysicalLocation table that is referenced from both tables. Then, you can also reference the PhysicalLocation table from your ElectricMeter table, or alternatively reference the ElectricMeter table from the PhysicalLocation (either is valid, since it is a one-to-one relationsship).

Comment: I am sorry but I am unable to understand how you are maintaining data in your tables?  Why you need two separate tables for maintaining meterno allocation? if only one meter can be allocated to user then why you don't have a single table and have another field saying TYPE (Domestic/Commercial)? and which field you are using for 'user'? 'AllocatedEmpID' in first table? and in second table which field?ShopID?Ownernic?

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use the meter no as foreign key
for example
DomesticQuater(QuaterNo,meterno,Location,Address,AllocatedEmpID)

CommercialShops(ShopId,meterno,Location,ownername,ownernic)

ElectricMeter(meterno,meterphase) 
so in this way against one meter no there will be one domestic user or a commerical user.